# Make a list from lists of DNA sequences

Tags: python, list

This is  an example of my pattern (sequence.fasta: note that every line ends with \n, the last line usually ends with \n\n)

```
>sequence1
TTGACCGATGACCCC
GGTTC
>sequence2
TTGACCGATGACCCC
GGTTCAGGCTTCACC
ACAG
>sequence3
TTGACCGATGACCCC
GGTTCAGGCTTCAC
```

a list that I need

```
[
   ['>sequence1','TTGACCGATGACCCCGGTTC'],
   ['>sequence2','TTGACCGATGACCCCGGTTCAGGCTTCACCACAG'],
   ['>sequence3','TTGACCGATGACCCCGGTTCAGGCTTCAC']
]
```

this is what I tried

```
with open(r"C:\Users\Lab\Desktop\sequence.fasta") as f:
    handle = f.read()
    # print(handle)
    pattern = re.compile(r'(>.+\n)(([A-Z]+\n*)+)')
    matches = pattern.finditer(handle)

    for match in matches:
        output = ['{}'.format(match.group(1)),'{}'.format(match.group(2)).replace("\n","")]
        print(output)
```

but thing I got is (it is 3 lists in one output)

```
   ['>sequence1','TTGACCGATGACCCCGGTTC']
   ['>sequence2','TTGACCGATGACCCCGGTTCAGGCTTCACCACAG']
   ['>sequence3','TTGACCGATGACCCCGGTTCAGGCTTCAC']
```

I already had tried to create a blank list and use `list.append()` or `list.extend()` and for loop to make a list from these lists but I cannot figure out how (I'm microbiologist). This is for DNA analysis further.

Appreciate your help
THANK YOU in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
output = []
with open(r"C:\Users\Lab\Desktop\sequence.fasta") as f:
    handle = f.read()
    # print(handle)
    pattern = re.compile(r'(>.+\n)(([A-Z]+\n*)+)')
    matches = pattern.finditer(handle)

    for match in matches:
        output.append(['{}'.format(match.group(1)),'{}'.format(match.group(2)).replace("\n","")])
print(output)
```

Comment: Toss a `output = []` somewhere ;)

Comment: @Guimonte nice catch! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with split and a list comprehension:

```
handle=""">sequence1
TTGACCGATGACCCC
GGTTC
>sequence2
TTGACCGATGACCCC
GGTTCAGGCTTCACC
ACAG
>sequence3
TTGACCGATGACCCC
GGTTCAGGCTTCAC"""

sequences = [[n,"".join(s)] for seq in handle.split(">")[1:] 
                            for n,*s in [seq.split("\n")]]
```

output:

```
sequences:

[
 ['sequence1', 'TTGACCGATGACCCCGGTTC'],
 ['sequence2', 'TTGACCGATGACCCCGGTTCAGGCTTCACCACAG'],
 ['sequence3', 'TTGACCGATGACCCCGGTTCAGGCTTCAC']
]
```